# Node.js OpenAPI 3 Validation Library

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

I have yet to see any libraries in existence that support OpenAPI request validation. Or to that matter any projects that are under active-development that does as such.

Would very much like to write middleware in my microservices to validate based on OpenAPI 3 specs instead of Swagger/OpenAPI 2 specs.

Examples

https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-express

https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-koa

Don't see anything listed - https://github.com/Mermade/awesome-openapi3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary solution is converting the OpenAPI 3 spec to a Swagger 2 spec, and then using a popular middleware tool for Swagger 2 Koa / etc to validate requests.

Here are a couple libraries I went with.

https://github.com/LucyBot-Inc/api-spec-converter
https://github.com/carlansley/swagger2-koa

Comment: Take a look at this npm-module. It looks like what you're looking for. https://github.com/isa-group/oas-tools#readme

Answer (score 1):

[express-openapi-validator](https://github.com/cdimascio/express-openapi-validator) validates API requests, responses, and securities against an OpenAPI 3 specification.

```
new OpenApiValidator({ 
  apiSpec: './openapi-spec.yaml', 
  validateRequests: true,
  validateResponses: true,
}).install(app);
```